# Oracle Lite 10g installer not detecting JDK on my mahine

Tags: windows, oracle, installation, java

I have a Windows 7 64-bit system, on which I have installed Java JDK 7 6-bit version ... Its installed in its default directory:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin`

I have also set the `JAVA_HOME` Environment variable to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0` in System Settings .. But still even now, during installation of Oracle Lite 10g, I get the error:

`JDK is not installed on machine`

What could be the problem now ?!?

EDIT:

I have also now added `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0` to the end of the `PATH` variable, and still the same result !

EDIT 2:

Completely removed ALL traces of Java from my system .. Uninstalled all Java things ! Used JavaRa to confirm everything is removed ! Removed any folders which are Java related ! Restarted system ! Reinstalled JDK 7 x64 version with a fresh downloaded copy ! Tried installing Oracle 10g Lite now after setting the above environment variable (now set it as a system variable), and STILL THE DAMN ERROR IS STILL THERE ! :(

Comment: Have you tried changing JAVA_HOME to that same path _without_ the `\bin` part? (Or possibly replacing that `\bin` by `\jre`, can't remember if it needs a full JDK or just the runtime.)

Comment: yes, JAVA_HOME without the \bin part please.

Comment: That was what I was doing in the first place. Writing `\bin` at the end was a typing mistake by me, which is corrected now ...

Comment: is there a possibility that you added a user-level environment variable and you're running the installer with higher privileges?

Comment: How can I make sure the environment variable I added was of administrative level ? ... I am the administrator of my system though ..

Comment: Try setting it as a system level variable as shown in this [figure 4](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html)

Comment: Completely removed ALL traces of Java from my system .. Uninstalled all Java things ! Used JavaRa to confirm everything is removed ! Removed any folders which are Java related ! Restarted system ! Reinstalled JDK 7 x64 version with a fresh downloaded copy ! Tried installing Oracle 10g Lite now after setting the above environment variable (now set it as a system variable), and STILL THE DAMN ERROR IS STILL THERE ! :(

Comment: @Ahmad [Oracle 10g lite requirements](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12095_01/doc.10303/e12080/preinstall.htm#CBHJDEGF) seem to say that Java 1.6 or later is not supported.

Comment: Hi. Im having the same problem. Seems that editing the server.xml doesnt help. Any luck on this error?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a supported configuration. You need to switch to a more current oracle release.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit]
"CurrentVersion"="1.7"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.7]
"JavaHome"="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_67"
"MicroVersion"="0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.7.0_67]
"JavaHome"="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_67"
"MicroVersion"="0"
```

Of course this may vary depending on the version of the Java Development Kit.  Copy what is located at **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit** in your registry to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit**.